# How to take input of a file name as an argument of a function?

Tags: c

In my code I scan for an input file which is then passed as an argument of a function. Is there a function that I can use to get the pathname of the file? The only input that is allowed is the filename.

Comment: Posting your code, so far, would add clarity and value to this question.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the file name from a file handle ?

Comment: No, there is no *search* function in C that will go looking for that filename. The usual assumption is that the file is in the current working directory, so you don't need a path.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the absolute path of a file given a relative path?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  It is not clear what you are asking for.  It usually helps to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) which shows what you're trying to do (how you 'scan for an input file') and where you're running into problems.

Answer (score -1):

Not, a file can have several names and the system doesn't maintain (once the file is open) the path used to open it.  In this scenario, determining uniquely what was the name used to open the file is ambiguous, so no provision is made.

Indeed, neither a file has a way to know which directory it belongs to, as several directories can have links to the file, so the path to a file can be multiple, and so, trying to decode which was the path used to open it is not feasible.

Assume you have a process that is executing with current working directory `/etc`.  You can open the file `/etc/passwd` with several different paths, for example, any of these will open the file for the sample process:

1. `open("/etc/passwd", ...);`
2. `open("passwd", ...);`
3. `open("./passwd", ...);`
4. `open("default/../passwd", ...);`
5. `open("/../../../etc/passwd", ...);`

etc...

If you need not only the file descriptor to the file, but also the name used to open, just pass both to the function.

## Note on comments to other posts

If the process inherited the current working directory from its parent proces, there is no way to know how the parent got to that directory (the path used) so the reference to the absolute path to the file is lost forever.  Since there are symbolic links, there's ambiguity also to determine the path to a directory also.

Files open with a relative path are relative to the current directory, which is a process property, that only is maintained by the kernel as a reference to an inode, so the path used to acquire such a directory is unknown to the process.  It's true that the *path to a directory*  can be known, as each directory has a `..` entry that points to it's parent directory, and so on to the root, whose `..` points to itself.

Determining the path to a directory in this way is an expensive operation, that requires to access the parent directory and search that directory for an entry whose inode number is the same as the actual directory inode number, and so on until we begin to repeat inode numbers (for the root directory)

As the current directory is inherited from the process parent, it can have been changed after the file was open, and so, you can have lost any relationship from the path you have (the one used to open the file, probably in the parent process) and the directory you inherited as current when you begun to execute.

Comment: A comment on the downvote will be appreciated, the post answers the response, that has a negative response.  There's no way to access the directory a file belongs to, simly because it can belong to several, as it is demostrated in the examples posted.

Answer (score -3):

Keep in mind that the program runs from a certain directory.  Just getting the current working directory should give you the path.

`getcwd()`

Comment: You can open a file not residing in your current directory.  What about opening `/etc/passwd` while running in directory `/home/user1/subdir`???  Your response is neither correct, nor useful (it is even unefficient, as `getcwd(2)` is a quite expensive function call.

Comment: @LuisColorado He was asking how to get the path of a file when just the filename is given.  If just the filename is given, it has to be in the current working directory.  Just get current working directory if the filename doesn't start with `/` or `./`.

Comment: even in that case, the response is ambiguous, as it is supposed the kernel only maintains a link to the inode (and not to the pathname of how the inode was acquired --- this could happen in the parent process)